# editing values of ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm fairly new to angularjs. I'm trying to edit the data in $scope.works. I've also tried xeditable, but could'nt really do much with it. I know its a simple thing to do. But your answers would be really helpful. Thanks.

Here's my code -

My angular.js code -

```
  $scope.works=[{id:'01', position:'web designer' ,place:'Artle'        ,month:'April',year:'2014',month1:'April',year1:'2015',city:'delhi'},
        {id:'02', position:'web designer' ,place:'Artle' ,month:'April',year:'2014',month1:'April',year1:'2015',city:'delhi'}];    



  $scope.editEnabled= false;

  $scope.editData=function(work){
    work.editEnabled = true;
  };

  $scope.saveData=function(data, id){

       angular.extend(data, {id: id});
return $http.post('/saveData', data);
  };


    $scope.close=function(work){
     work.editEnabled = false;
    }
   $scope.editEnabled = false;
  $scope.disableEdit= function(){
    $scope.editEnabled = false;
  };
});
```

For editing and saving the changes, my html is-

```
      <span ng-hide="work.editEnabled">
       <button ng-click="editData(work) ">Edit</button>
   </span>
   <span ng-show="work.editEnabled">
       <button ng-click="close(work);saveData($data, work.id); ">Save</button>


</script>
```

On click of edit I've shown the values in input. The problem is, on click of save the new changes made in input wouldnt save, it'd show it as it is in $scope.works

Comment: Please clean up the code to just contain the necessary bits & pieces.

Comment: Just did it. Kindly check it again

Comment: Are you somehow confusing two different things here, `work.editEnabled` and `$scope.editEnabled` ?

Comment: no no, that works fine. I've checked it. The problem is with saveData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your save data is not working, its bind incorrectly change it to this:

```
<button ng-click="saveData(work, work.id); ">Save</button>
```

You need to pass `work` data not `$data`
Remove two functions from `ng-clik` leave only save data,and call close in saveData function

```
 $scope.saveData=function(data, id){
      $scope.close(data);
       angular.extend(data, {id: id});
       return $http.post('/saveData', data);
  };
```

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. Also do i need to make changes in my script where the function is placed ?

Comment: try removing close(work) and call it in saveData function. do not put two or more function callss

Comment: did it, still it isnt working. The problem is with saveData -           $scope.saveData=function(data, id){
 angular.extend(data, {id: id});
    return $http.post('/saveData', data);
      };

Comment: did you print out data in that function is that data ok? If it is, then problem is with your Post request, maybe there is a problem.

Comment: Hi, i just saw your update. I made the necessary changes. Hide and show works but data doesn't change.

Comment: Let me check post again.

Comment: checked it. Cant understand the problem :(